# Get only the Nth occurence of a string using .net Regex only

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Please some help. I'm trying already by more than 2 days... and it is frustrating for me.

If you have any idea would be so helpful:

Having the following text and using Regex in .NET:

```
   -------------------------------------
   This is a text   : This is my first line of information
                      which continues here
                    : This is my second line of information
                      which continues here
                    : This is my third line of information
                      which continues here
   -------------------------------------
```

How could I get:
   - "This is my first line of information which continues here"
   - "This is my second line of information which continues here"
   - "This is my third line of information which continues here"

A practical example:  [Trying to read line by line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNTSQ.png)
  Please consider the text dynamic.

The best regex expression that I was able to obtain is:

```
 (?ms)((?<=(:)).*?(?=(\:)))
```

1. How can I read starting from ": This is my second line" or ": This is my third line"
2. How can I replace the white spaces between "This is my first line of information" and "which continues here".

Thanks a lot. 
Radu.

Comment: Try `(?<=:)[^:]+`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fms%29%28%3f%3c%3d%3a%29%5b%5e%3a%5d%2b&i=+++This+is+a+text+++%3a+This+is+my+first+line+of+information%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++which+continues+here%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++%3a+This+is+my+second+line+of+information%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++which+continues+here%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++%3a+This+is+my+third+line+of+information%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++which+continues+here).

Comment: read all, split on colon, remove first item,  then for each item replace multiple spaces to single space and trim

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tgWFD2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It is ok that one, but how can I start with the second line ?
I don't have the luxury of using code. Regex only :(

Comment: What do you mean? You want to have 3 different regex patterns? *How can I replace the white spaces* - only with regex *replacement funtion/method*, there is no way to match discontinuous pieces of text within one match operation - no regex allows you that.

Comment: I was thinking to something like:

- ...some regex...**{1}**...regex....   - to get :"This is my first line of information which continues here"
...some regex...**{2}**...regex....   - to get :"This is my second line of information which continues here"
...some regex...**{3}**...regex....   - to get :"This is my third line of information which continues here"

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all you need, but unfortunately also a bit toot much

https://regex101.com/r/5lcWku/1

`/:[^:]+$/gm`

The issue is that you will never be able to match the last line without also matching everything that comes after that because you have no way of knowing if what comes after the last line is still valid or not (or at least you didn't provide one in our original question).

Comment: @FP: Thanks , but how can I start from the second ":" onwards ?

Comment: That is a bit hard to do in regex without making it completely unreadable. I'd advise to iterate over the captured groups and skip the first one.